# Button click to replace images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I want to replace the question mark icon with a yellow question mark icon when support is clicked. When I click the icon remains the same. I don't know where the code is going wrong. Thanks for help.

[image: image change]

```
function selectAvatar(this){
  var imgSrc = element.src;
  document.getElementById("img-change").src = imgSrc;
}
```

```html
<a onClick="selectAvatar(this)" href="support.php"  src="images/support_yellow.png">
<img id="img-change" src="images/support_black.png">
```

Comment: What is `element`? I'm assuming you meant to name the function argument `element` instead of `this`

Comment: voting to close as a typo

Comment: `a` tags have no `src` attribute

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so the element have to declared? i am newbie for coding. sry.

Comment: It will not work even after changing this to element. Because this `a` tag has `onclick` as well as `href`. `href` will load the new page. so the image will also reset. I think you have to set the image in `support.php`

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the `this` parameter to `element`

```
function selectAvatar(element) {
  var imgSrc = element.src;
  document.getElementById("img-change").src = imgSrc;
}
```

Comment: I doubt this... because this `a` tag has `onclick` as well as `href`

Comment: @SankarRaj But `element` was undefined.

Comment: sorry i am newbie, i have try change this--->element. still cannot work.

Comment: sure. this will be the solution for changing image. but `href` will load the new page. so the image will also  reset

Answer (score 0):

Make two images under each other like:

```
<img src="img1.jpg" id="img1">
<img src="img2.jpg" id="img2">
```

Give one of the pictures the property: `display:none`

```
<img src="img1.jpg" id="img1" style="display:none">
```

Than the javascript to hide one and display the other one:

```
document.getElementById("img2").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("img1").style.display = "inline";
```

See more information about this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp).